# Remove quotations that surrounds substring but keep standalone quotes

Tags: python, regex

I want to remove quotes that surrounds substrings, but I want to keep quotes that does not surround any substring.

```
dq = 'EXAMPLE "DOUBLE QUOTE" bla 8.54" (inches) long'   
>>> 'EXAMPLE "DOUBLE QUOTE" bla 8.54" (inches) long'

ds = 'EXAMPLE \'SINGLE QUOTE\' bla 1900\' (feet) long'
>>> "EXAMPLE 'SINGLE QUOTE' bla 1900' (feet) long"
```

So I want to remove quotations like `"DOUBLE QUOTE"` and `'SINGLE QUOTE'`, but I need to keep standalone quotations like `8.54"` and `1900'`, which are important as they represent units of length in inches and feet.

How can I do this?

Comment: It is hard to tell in your example which quote surrounds. If you want to remove first surrounded quote, it will be ppssible using regex

Comment: @Rahul please check the edits

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you suppose that quoted strings come after a space or are at the start of the string (using this group `(\s|^)`, you could differentiate the unit from them:

```
import re

dq = 'EXAMPLE 15" "DOUBLE QUOTE" bla 8.54" (inches) long'  # added another 15" string

print(re.sub('(\s|^)[\'"](.*?)[\'"]',r"\1\2",dq))  # non-greedy substitution
```

outputs:

```
EXAMPLE 15" DOUBLE QUOTE bla 8.54" (inches) long
```